# T-test or ANOVA

Tags: anova, t-test

I have 4 groups.  I would like to compare the effect of 3 different treatments relating to drug treatment of a sample individually against a single control sample.

Control (no drug)
Treatment A (low concentration of drug)
Treatment B (medium concentration of drug)
Treatment C (high concentration of drug)

What test should I use?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this for a course? Other than "low", "medium" & "high", do you know what the concentrations are?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply.  My question relates to cells grown in a dish and exposed to a drug for 24 hours. One was the control group (N=5) and was not treated with a drug. One was treated with a 'low' concentration of a drug (0.1mg/kg) (N=5),

Comment: another with a 'medium' concentration of the same drug (1.0mg/kg) (N=5) and another with a 'high' concentration of the same drug (2.5mg/kg) (N=5).  I have detected changes in the level of certain proteins in my drug treated groups that appear to be related to the concentration of drug.  i.e. the higher the concentration the greater the change in protein.  I want to compare each of the drug treated groups against the control, not necessarily between all groups together.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> What test should I use?

I'd start with "what model should I use?".

You *could* simply compare each treatment with the control, perhaps via something like [*Dunnett's test*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test), but that would miss the ability to infer the way that the response relates to dosage -- your treatments are not "treatment 1"/"treatment 2"/"treatment 3" but ordered levels of dosage on a single treatment (and as such you might perhaps expect an ordered response).

The other issue may be that protein levels (which I take to be your response) may be skewed and heteroskedastic - which would suggest you might be best with some GLM, whether you're looking for an equivalent of a t-test or an equivalent of ANOVA.

However, to make the fullest use of your information, I'd think that either a regression (or perhaps more likely, a GLM) would be a suitable way to model the response to the concentration of the drug.